# Query just like Stackoverflow 5 questions in 24 hours limitation query alike?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Table TblQuestions :

```
UserId     time    
------------------
1           1-1-2012 10:14
1           1-2-2012 11:15
1           1-3-2012 12:18
1           1-14-2012 13:15
1           1-16-2012 14:14
2           1-16-2012 10:15
2           1-16-2012 10:15
...
...
```

I want to build a query that checks if a user has already posted  5 question in an 24 hours interval.

just like stackoverflow.

I need an efficient query (by userId) that returns me "allow" or "disAllow" -like bit field...

p.s.

if the query has **already found** more than 5 question in 24 hours interval - DONT continue scanning  - just return - "disAllow"....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you asked **NOT** for arbitrary interval but for the last 24 hours from now, then:

```
IF (
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM YOURTABLE 
     WHERE 
         UserId = @UserId 
     AND [time] >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
   ) > 5
  SELECT 'disAllow'
ELSE
  SELECT 'Allow'
```